# mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in E:\Program Files (x86)\XAMPP\htdocs\ePro\My_account_info.php on line 13

Tags: parameters

```
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_login = 'root';
$db_password = '';
$db_name = "epro";
$conn = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_login, $db_password);
$db = mysql_select_db($db_name);
```

$query = "SELECT  FROM `registration_details`";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
enter code here
```

Comment: Can you express the problem that you're having as a question?

Answer (score 1):

As they keep saying, mysql extension has been deprecated and mysqli/PDO should be used now. However, it could be that you are maintaining a legacy system.

1. I would first of all check if that SELECT query worked (as a good practice):

   ```
   $result = mysql_query($query);
   if(!$result) {
           die...
   }
   else {
   ... fetch array, etc ...
   ```
2. Your query is missing the "*" or params. "SELECT * FROM db"